# noConflict in Coffeescript?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I have the following JavaScript for a datepicker in my rails application but I want to use coffeescript and I am wondering how to implement no conflict on this function in coffeescript?

```
<script>
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();     
$(function(){
  $('#datepicker').fdatepicker({
    initialDate: '02-12-1989',
    format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
    disableDblClickSelection: true
  });
});
</script>
```

Also the above works but I have to refresh the page before it does. Any advice on both? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what it might look like in CoffeeScript.

```
$j = jQuery.noConflict()
$ ->
  $('#datepicker').fdatepicker
    initialDate: '02-12-1989'
    format: 'dd-mm-yyyy'
    disableDblClickSelection: true
  return
```

When it runs in the browser it's still running as JavaScript so the functionality `jQuery.noConflict()` offers is still going to be there.